# How to configure oplog url for mongdb with sharding enabled in Rocket.Chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I have configured mongodb with sharding enabled. I don't find any Rocket.Chat documentation on what should be the oplogurl.

Comment: How should we help you without the details of your configuration? We can not help you this way because we can not understand your problem like that.

Comment: Rocket.chat is built on meteor.  Meteor does not support sharded mongo databases.  You can point to a single replicaset in the shard I believe.  But at that point you get no benefit of sharding

Comment: Thank you Aaron. It is clear now.